# Could not find chunky_png-1.3.3 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby, terminal, zurb-foundation, gem-bundler

When I try to run a new Foundation Projekt over the Terminal, this line above seems to make my projekt not running correctly. The whole answer here:

```
xxxxxMacBookAir:htdocs xxxxx$ foundation new _lutz2015
Creating ./_lutz2015
      create  _lutz2015
Cloning into '_lutz2015'...
remote: Counting objects: 117, done.
remote: Total 117 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (117/117), 40.07 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (46/46), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Installing dependencies with bower...
         run  compass compile from "./_lutz2015"
/Users/xxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize': Could not find chunky_png-1.3.3 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
    from /Users/xxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
    from /Users/xxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
    from /Users/xxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:132:in `specs'
    from /Users/xxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:177:in `specs_for'
    from /Users/xxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
    from /Users/xxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `setup'
    from /Users/xxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler.rb:133:in `require'
    from /Users/xxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/compass-1.0.1/bin/compass:26:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/xxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/compass:23:in `load'
    from /Users/xxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/compass:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/xxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/xxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
./_lutz2015 was created
xxxxxMacBookAir:htdocs xxxxx$
```

Comment: try running `gem install chunky_png`

Comment: thanks for that. i installed chunky_png. After that terminal could not find sass 4.x.x. After installing sass terminal could not find ffi-1.9.6. This one, i could not install. I got an error. It seems, there are a few things upside down. Is it possible, that i should install something totally new?? What would that be?

Comment: so `gem install ffi` didn't work?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. But you should just `cd` into `'_lutz2015'` and run `bundle` (only once per project). This will resolve all dependencies and is much easier. Basically, the following will be installed ( you will need to have installed bundler, of course) :

```
chunky_png x.x.x
multi_json x.x.x
sass x.x.x
compass-core x.x.x
compass-import-once x.x.x
rb-fsevent x.x.x
ffi x.x.x
rb-inotify x.x.x
```